# Batch parameter via double click

Tags: windows, parameters, batch-file, dos

i would like to create a batch script and run it via double click,
but the commands that i use, need a parameter

example: the bat file open the prompt and ask for a parameter, then it create a diredtory with that parameter as name
(in reality is a parameter to give to plink, but the example is similar)

How can i do that?

i know how to get a parameter via command line:

```
@echo off
mkdir %1
```

but how to do that via double click?

Answer (score 1):

This may help. Describes how to prompt from batch file for the various versions of windows through the ages.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic form of what you are after:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P FOLDER=Enter a folder name: 
MKDIR "%1"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can click the parameter(s) in morse code. It will then be interpreted by Windows correctly. Make sure to get your timing right though.